# Code returning "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var initialValue = ""
    @State private var typeOfTemp = 0
    @State private var conversion = 0
    
    let types = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]
    
    func returnRightTemp(input:Double, output:Double, value:String) -> Double{
        var newValue = Double(value) ?? 0
        
        switch input{
        case 0:
            break
        case 1:
            newValue = (newValue - 32) * 0.5556
        case 2:
            newValue = newValue - 257.15
        default:
            print("Please pick from 0-2")
            
        }
        
        
        switch output {
        case 0:
            break
        case 1:
            newValue = ((newValue/5) * 9) + 32
        case 3:
            newValue = newValue + 273.15
            
        default:
            print("Please pick from 0-2")
        }
        
        return newValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section{
                    TextField("Enter value you wish to convert", text: $initialValue)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    
                }
                Section(header: Text("Input Temp")){
                    Picker("Initial Temp", selection: $typeOfTemp) {
                        ForEach(0..<types.count){
                            Text("\(types[$0])")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                Section(header: Text("Output Temp")){
                    Picker("Initial Temp", selection: $conversion) {
                        ForEach(0..<types.count){
                            Text("\(types[$0])")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                Section{
                    Text("\(returnRightTemp(input: self.typeOfTemp, output: self.conversion, value: self.initialValue))"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I call the returnRightTemp function, it has an error pop up that says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I've never seen this type of error before and can't find any resources to help me. Any thing to help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you once again. Another thing I would like to know, how would you change the function to a closure? I did try to implement it, but I might have messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass `Int` values to a function that takes `Double`s.

Change your signature to:

```
func returnRightTemp(input: Int, output: Int, value: String) -> Double {
```

Comment: Why would you want to turn the function into a closure?  You lose the ability to use named arguments.

Comment: Did this answer help? If so, please accept it by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left to turn it green. If not, leave a comment.